# A/B test: Metric for event count, not conversion

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

Is it possible on firebase A/B tests to monitor the event counts instead of the conversion rates?

For example, I would like to know if users in Variant A trigger a certain event more times than the Baseline (not only if they trigger the event or not, but how many times they trigger it).

[image: firebase a/b test screenshot]

Thanks!
Oriol

Answer (score 0):

That's a really good question.  For each event that is triggered, you should be able to derive event count as well as an event DAU metric.  Firebase has limited capability to run such analysis.  One way to do this is to download the data and run a manual analysis.  Or use a tool like [Statsig](https://statsig.com) that allows you compute these metrics automatically.  Here's a screenshot of what you get for every A/B experiment, and you can see how the tool breaks down Event Count and Event DAU for each metric.

[image]

Disclaimer: I work at Statsig.